# Use Windows Key to switch input language

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, input-languages

My PC has 2 input language and use Alt+` as switch currently.

As I usually use command key to switch input language in mac os, mistyping of windows key occurs so many time that I would like to set windows key as switch instead to rise the start menu. That two keys are in same place in my keyboard.

Is there any application like Remap4Macbook in Windows?
Any answers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is provided from [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Write the script like below, and that will prevent windows key from raising start menu and provide switching of input languages.

```
#z::Run www.autohotkey.com

^!n::

~LWin Up:: PostMessage, 0x50, 0x02,0,, A
~RWin Up:: PostMessage, 0x50, 0x02,0,, A

return
```

If you want windows key switch language to specific one, use LCID instead of `0x02`.
In following sample, pressing right windows key will change language to `en-US`. The List of LCID will be found in [this MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001).

```
#z::Run www.autohotkey.com

^!n::

~LWin Up:: PostMessage, 0x50, 0x02,0,, A
~RWin Up:: PostMessage, 0x50, 0x0409,0,, A

return
```

Hope this will help someone having same demand.